# How to improve Airflow task concurrency

Tags: concurrency, airflow, mwaa

I have question about dag and task concurrency.

**Scneario:**

I have two DAG files

DAG 1 has only one task

DAG 2 has three tasks, From three, one task is calling third party API (Third party API response time is 900 miliseconds, it is simple weather API for showing current weather of provided city. e.g https://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=api_key&q=Londodn ) and other 2 task are just for logs(print statment)

I trigger DAG 1 with the custom payloads having 1000 records

```
(
  for e.g. 
    conf: {
      [
        {
          "city": "London",
          ...
        },
        {
          ...
        }
      ]
    }
)
```

DAG 1 task just loop though the records and call the DAG 2 1000 times with individual record

So first, I want to ask here about this approach. Is this a good approach to call the list of data with 2 DAGs or is there any better way to do this?

My concern is it is taking 17 minutes for DAG 2 to process all 1000 execution

I am using Managed Workflow (AWS) configuration are as below:

```
Environment class: mw1.large
Scheduler count: 4
Maximum worker count: 25
Minimum worker count: 20
Region: us-west-2
core.max_active_runs_per_dag: 1000
core.max_active_tasks_per_dag: 5000
```

Default MWAA config for task as per aws documentation
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/best-practices-tuning.html)

```
core.parallelism: 10000
core.dag_concurrency: 10000
```

Can anyone guide me how can I improve my AWS Managed Airflow performance to improve the parallelism of DAG run?

I want to understand the parallelism and concurrency settings if they are set to this high as above configs are then why it takes 17 minutes for Airflow to complete tasks?

Thanks!